# Second patch does not updates system

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I've created a base product, a patch and a followed patch. For example there are three files: AAA.dll will be updated by 1st patch and by 2nd patch; BBB.dll will be updated by 1st patch and CCC.dll will be updated by 2nd patch.
Add GUIDs are static.

### Scenario 1:

- Install base MSI
- Install 1st Patch
- Result: all files are correctly updated

### Scenario 2:

- Install base MSI
- Install 2nd Patch
- Result: all files are correctly updated

### Scenario 3:

- Install base MSI
- Install 1st Patch
- Install 2nd Patch
- Result: AAA.dll was not updated and looks like there is only 1st patch installed

### Scenario 4:

- Install base MSI
- Install 1st Patch
- Install 2nd Patch
- Uninstall 1st Patch
- Result: everything is OK (BBB.dll is restored and AAA.dll has the version, that was included into 2nd patch)

### Scenario 5:

- Install base MSI
- Install 2st Patch
- Install 1nd Patch
- Result: AAA.dll was downgraded

Any ideas, what it could be?

**Small update:** 1st patch contains several registry keys, which are not included into 2nd patch. Could this cause the wrong behavior?

**One more update:** added Scenario 5.

### **More details**

It looks like there is something wrong with sequenser. Here is a small log piece of the log file:

```
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Tables 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Columns 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: The patch sequencer will optimize its execution by not checking the applicability of applied patches.
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PATCH SEQUENCER: verifying the applicability of QFE patch D:\Vadim\Build 10878\Packages\Patch_5.3.1.152\Patch_5.3.1.152.msp against product code: {E19A7576-0466-4156-A8B1-2796EFBF38CD}, product version: 5.3.1.118, product language 1033 and upgrade code: {AB899CB4-E853-4203-B867-2B6E6A3F2F2B}
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: Validating transform '_5.3.1.118.1' with validation bits 0x922
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: Transform '_5.3.1.118.1' is valid.
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PATCH SEQUENCER: QFE patch D:\Vadim\Build 10878\Packages\Patch_5.3.1.152\Patch_5.3.1.152.msp is applicable.
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: The original #_QFESequence table:
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PatchGUID: {70D34A3C-342B-4DB9-A163-C26DC50342CF}   ResultantVersion: 5.3.1.118 PatchFamily: Hotfix__3  Sequence: 5.3.1.148 Type: QFE
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PatchGUID: {0678A98C-E04D-4FC2-96C3-CA850D964BD0}   ResultantVersion: 5.3.1.118 PatchFamily: Hotfix__4  Sequence: 5.3.1.152 Type: QFE
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: The pre-sorted #_QFESequence table: - this is useful to see if patches had been ordered correctly within resultant versions and patch families
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PatchGUID: {70D34A3C-342B-4DB9-A163-C26DC50342CF}   ResultantVersion: 5.3.1.118 PatchFamily: Hotfix__3  Sequence: 5.3.1.148 VersionOrder: 0 SequenceOrder: 0    Type: QFE
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PatchGUID: {0678A98C-E04D-4FC2-96C3-CA850D964BD0}   ResultantVersion: 5.3.1.118 PatchFamily: Hotfix__4  Sequence: 5.3.1.152 VersionOrder: 0 SequenceOrder: 0    Type: QFE
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PATCH SEQUENCER: The initial #_Predecessor table:
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PatchFamily: Hotfix__3, PatchGUID: {70D34A3C-342B-4DB9-A163-C26DC50342CF},  Predecessor GUID: NULL
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PatchFamily: Hotfix__4, PatchGUID: {0678A98C-E04D-4FC2-96C3-CA850D964BD0},  Predecessor GUID: NULL
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PATCH SEQUENCER: Step 1
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PATCH SEQUENCER: patch {70D34A3C-342B-4DB9-A163-C26DC50342CF} (PatchFamily Hotfix__3) will be sequenced.
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PATCH SEQUENCER: patch {0678A98C-E04D-4FC2-96C3-CA850D964BD0} (PatchFamily Hotfix__4) will be sequenced.
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PATCH SEQUENCER: The resulting #_OrderedGUIDs table:
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: Patch: {0678A98C-E04D-4FC2-96C3-CA850D964BD0}   Order: 0    (Family: Hotfix__4)
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: Patch: {70D34A3C-342B-4DB9-A163-C26DC50342CF}   Order: 1    (Family: Hotfix__3)
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: The ordered #_QFESequence table: - has the final sequence of QFEs.  It lists each PatchGUID only once.
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PatchGUID: {0678A98C-E04D-4FC2-96C3-CA850D964BD0}   ResultantVersion: 5.3.1.118 PatchFamily: Hotfix__4  Sequence: 5.3.1.152 Order: 0
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PatchGUID: {70D34A3C-342B-4DB9-A163-C26DC50342CF}   ResultantVersion: 5.3.1.118 PatchFamily: Hotfix__3  Sequence: 5.3.1.148 Order: 1
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PATCH SEQUENCER: there's no supersedence information available, so no patches will be superseded.
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: SequencePatches returns success.
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: Final Patch Application Order:
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: {0678A98C-E04D-4FC2-96C3-CA850D964BD0} - D:\Vadim\Build 10878\Packages\Patch_5.3.1.152\Patch_5.3.1.152.msp
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: {70D34A3C-342B-4DB9-A163-C26DC50342CF} - 
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:396]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
```

But why? And how could i fix it? There was no problems with a small test product, which was build in the same way as the real one. But in this case base MSI of the real product is > 600Mb and patch is ca. 48Mb. Could this be a problem?

### **Upd**

My suggestion was proved by a small patch. for me, this looks like this is a MS bug. Does any one know, if it's possible to contact MS and ask if it's a know bug or feature? Or eventually create and track bug report?

Comment: Do you think you can share the logs from each of the problematic scenarios? There could be a lot of factors here such as the value of REINSTALLMODE  used,  the patch sequence numbers for each of the patches, . Logs would make it a lot easier  to troubleshoot this.

Comment: It's quite difficult with logs. I don't have a small test product and logs of the installations are 24Mb and 27Mb. REINSTALLMODE property not used.

Comment: Are you saying that its difficult to upload the logs here? If  so, can you provide me with access to them using  dropbox. I am sure REINSTALLMODE  has been used. You might not have used REINSTALLMODE explicitly on the command line but it gets used by default or via some other means.  Also, do you see any SELMGR  errors in your log files?

Comment: No, there is no 'REINSTALLMODE' word in log file at all. And there is nothing unusual with SELMGR as well. This seems to be a problem with sequencer... I've updated my first post.

Comment: Well, why is the patch sequencer sequencing Patch 4 earlier to Patch 3, even though Patch 4 has a higher patch sequence number? Thats the problem. That explains the downgrade of AAA.dll in scenario 5. Let me try to dig more about this problem.

Comment: How are you generating this patch?  Can youi please provide more details?

Comment: The patch will be generated by WiX
1) i'm getting base MSI; 2) generate new MSI; 3) generate WiX for patch; 4) do administrative install for base MSI and for new generated MSI; 5) tourch -> candle -> light -> pyro

Comment: One more strange thing - initially patches are sorted correctly, and they will be reordered after 'MSI (c) (F4:00) [17:38:09:395]: PATCH SEQUENCER: The resulting #_OrderedGUIDs table:' And the order of patches corresponds not to 'Sequence', but to PatchGUID. I'll check this assumption with my test product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was quite trivial - we have used different "Patch Family" names.

There is everything OK, when the same "Patch Family" will be used.